# Issue with "update-data" in Package Manger Console 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, visual-studio-2022, desktop-application

[2nd  error realted to update-database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCjkK.png)
Second Error related to "update-database" in Package Manger Console
The 1st error at the previous question was gone after editing the connection name on "program.cs"
Still won't be "Done" with the " update-database"

It should show "Done" on Pacake Manger Console

Comment: This error typically occurs in client environments such as docker image containers, Unix clients, or Windows clients, where TLS 1.2 is the lowest supported TLS protocol version.
Recommended solution: Install the latest update on a supported version of SQL Server and ensure that the TLS 1.2 protocol is enabled on the server.
Check the SqlClient driver support lifecycle for [a list of supported SQL Server versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-driver-support-lifecycle?view=sql-server-ver15) including different versions of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.